# PasswordStrength Extender Not showing text description

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement the passwordstrength feature in my web app. But, the text descriptions don't appear, only "xx character left". What is wrong with my code?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
    </td>
</tr>

<asp:PasswordStrength ID="txtPassword_PasswordStrength" runat="server" 
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtPassword" PreferredPasswordLength="10" 
TextCssClass="TextIndicator_TextBox1" 
RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="True"  
HelpStatusLabelID="Label10" 
TextStrengthDescriptions="Poor;Weak;Average;Strong;Excellent" 
StrengthIndicatorType="Text" PrefixText="Strength:" 
MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="0" 
MinimumNumericCharacters="0" MinimumSymbolCharacters="0" 
MinimumUpperCaseCharacters="0" DisplayPosition="RightSide" />
```

Answer (score 0):

missing the property

```
CalculationWeightings="25;25;15;35"
```

If you change one these props to 1 because the current setting doesnt seem logic to me

```
RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="True"  
MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="0"
MinimumUpperCaseCharacters="0"
```

Label10 present?

Comment: Yup Label10 present and changing props to 1 doesn't have any effect

Comment: Ok I created another project and tried the same code. It works, but I don't understand why i cannot get it to work in my project! Might it be because I am using the extender within an update panel in a modalpopup extender? I really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Well, it appears that the password strength extender not working might have something to do with modalpopup extender. I tried the code in and outside a modalpopup extender. It works outside but does not work within a modalpoup extender.

Comment: From similar issues it seems that the password strength messages appear behind the modalpopup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<asp:PasswordStrength ID="txtPassword_PasswordStrength" runat="server" 
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtPassword" PreferredPasswordLength="10" 
TextCssClass="TextIndicator_TextBox1" 
RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="True"  
HelpStatusLabelID="Label10" 
TextStrengthDescriptions="Poor;Weak;Average;Strong;Excellent" 
StrengthIndicatorType="Text" PrefixText="Strength:" 
MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="1" 
MinimumNumericCharacters="1" MinimumSymbolCharacters="1" 
MinimumUpperCaseCharacters="1" DisplayPosition="RightSide" />
```